# Angular ng build not working - blocked at complie keepalive

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ng

When I tried to use the 'ng build' to build the project. It just blocked at compling the keepalve.
Here is the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8JLt.png).
The command is 'node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build'
My node version is 14.18.0 (then I switch to 14.20.1)
My npm version is 6.14.17.

Before doing the 'ng build', what I do is:

1. rm -rf ./node_modules
2. rm package-lock.json
3. npm cache clean --force (3~4 times)
4. npm install

But it is still not work. I did not change anything about the code. Just suddently, I rebuild the project, it occur this. In the meantime, there is not any error throw out in the terminal. My operation system is Windows.

Also, I tried to increase the --max_old_space_size to a larger number, it is still not work.

And, I tried to update the node version into 14.20.1. It is not work too.